# Shortcut folder as directory in php

Tags: php

Is there any possibility in to make shortcut folder recognize as directory using PHP `is_dir` function?

For example:

```
is_dir($shortcut_folder_path)
```

I have tried several possibilities however couldn't find a specific solution for it. On doing `var_dump($shortcut_folder_path)` always returns false not recognizing it as directory.

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: What do you mean by the shortcut folder? How is the `$shortcut_folder_path` variable created? Please add the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `is_link` instead of `is_dir` to know if the a file is a shortcut/symbolic link.

Have a look at it:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-link.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scandir` function. If you specify the path to the directory it will return an array containing files and directories from that directory.So if your directory exists you will get the array as return, if it doesn't it will return oolean false.

[php documentation for scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)